# Can I declare the list of interfaces inline within the slice?

Tags: go, range, slice

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a A
    var b B

    for _, v := range []WhatAreYou{a, b} {
        fmt.Println(v.Question())
    }
}

type WhatAreYou interface {
    Question() string
}

type A struct {
    string
}

type B struct {
    int
}

func (a A) Question() string {
    return "I'm an A"
}

func (b B) Question() string {
    return "I'm a B"
}
```

The code above works as I expect and calls the function on each interface as expected. [Go Play](https://play.golang.org/p/8fBbNKATuml)

In my actual code I intend to have many different types implementing an interface. How can I get rid of the var a A var b B etc and simply declare them all in the slice? i.e. I tried and failed with the following and other variations

```
for _, v := range []WhatAreYou{a A, b B} {
```

Comment: `[]WhatAreYou{A{}, B{}}` https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals

Comment: Thanks. Seems kind of obvious now I've been shown. Thanks for the link that was exactly what i was trying to Google for but didn't think of the phrase composite literal

Comment: Why these downvotes - I see a concise question with a working code example. Just beeing a beginners level question is not against the rules, right?

Comment: @shful: I wondered that too but I got the answer and I've got golang to learn so I let it be. Would like to know what I can do to improve, but I'm not going to lose sleep over a few down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[]WhatAreYou{A{}, B{}}

This is correct, thanks to mkopriva. [Composite Literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

Now I understand a little better what I am doing here I think I understand why this question is down voted too. The question doesn't really make sense. I was so hung up on the idea of the interface I didn't think of anything else. var a A is declaring a struct that happens to implement an interface. This is even more obvious if you initialise the struct e.g. var a = A{"hello"} or inline A{"hello"}, B{2}